Postgres + SQLAlchemy + psycopg3: handling sequence column with an upsert operation
I have the following table:
    test = Table('test', meta,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True),
        Column('name', String, unique= True),
        Column('description', String),

In the above, the id column becomes a SERIAL column in the postgres table.
I want to be able to do bulk inserts and handle cases where the id column may or may not be null (basically an upsert).  by sql looks like this (after having inserted the records i want to upsert into tmp_tbl)
insert into test(id,name) select * from tmp_tbl on conflict(id) do update set name = EXCLUDED.name;drop table if exists tmp_tbl;

The problem with this is if 'id' is null, i get a constraint error.  if id is not null, it works fine.
'null value in column "id" of relation "test" violates not-null constraint

Is there away of handling this elegantly without having to do the two operations separately (insert and update)
Thanks
EDIT:
i can solve this by first doing something like this before the insert..
UPDATE tmp_tbl SET id = nextval('test_id_seq') WHERE id IS NULL;

Dont know if that is the best or recommended way however

Break it into two steps 1) insert into test(id,name) select * from tmp_tbl where id is not null ... 2) insert into test(name) select  name from tmp_tbl where id is null.

As no one posted a solution, the solution i worked with was what i mentioned in my edit.  That is to first update the tmp_tbl with the new ids for the serial column by using the 'next_val' function, then doing the insert.
UPDATE tmp_tbl SET id = nextval('test_id_seq') WHERE id IS NULL;

